# Show a metrix space is connected iff for every non-empty proper subset the boundary is non-empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show a metric space X is connected iff \forall non-empty proper subset A \subset X the boundary (set of points in X whose neighborhoods contain points from both A and the complement) is non-empty.

Comment: What definition of connected are you using?

Comment: if it cannot be written as the union of two disjoint, non-empty closed (or open) subsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is disconnected, so $X = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint non-empty  closed (and open) subsets. 
What is $\operatorname{Bd}(A)$?

Suppose $A$ is non-empty and suppose $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \emptyset$; as the boundary of $A$ is the difference between closure and interior of $A$, we have that these coincide and so $A$ is clopen. So $X = A \cup \ldots $ proves $X$ is disconnected.

Comment: A union A complement?

Comment: Indeed. And $X \setminus A$ is also...

Comment: X \ A is also A complement? or B? Are you allowed to say both of those?

Comment: $B = X \setminus A$, one could say. But closed and open is what I meant.

Comment: I'm trying to let it sink in.